# Can I avoid getting progression-skipping items from the Digital Deluxe Edition?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

I am interested in getting Digital Deluxe Edition of [Sonic Frontiers](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1237320/Sonic_Frontiers/) for the included digital art book, soundtrack, and cosmetic gloves. However, I don't want any progression-skipping items like Amy's Memory Tokens, the Chaos Emerald Vault Keys, and the Portal Gear.

Is it possible to avoid collecting the progression skipping items if I buy the Digital Deluxe Edition?

[image: Sonic Frontiers Deluxe Edition bonuses]

Comment: What? You mean that you are one of the "few fools" that don't appreciate Sega gift of giving you the ability to not play the game you just bought?.... 
That is ironic obviously, [you are not the only one that was really annoyed by that stupid DLC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn6mwIG5eZg&t=52s)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Shoes are an outfit, just like the (far better and FREE) Monster Hunter armor. As such they are enabled/disabled in the main menu of the game, before you load a save slot.

[image]

This also means that once you manage to get the shoes, you can enable them when you want, on any slot you want.

Problem is that the shoes are actually listed as a part of the Explorer Box set, so they probably are part of the same DLC download item and can't be installed without enabling the stupid Treasure Box (congrats! You paid for the privilege to skip playing the game!).

[image]

There is a caveat though:

[image]

This implies that the game only checks for the presence of the two Treasure Box DLC at the start of the game, before you complete the tutorial.

See where this is going?

- Install the game
- Play the tutorial
- Install the Explorer Treasure
- Start the game. You can now enable the shoes in the extra section of the main menu, but since you already completed the tutorial that save slot won't ever receive the items...

This obviously assumes that everything Sega wrote is actually correct and that you can install and start the game without downloading the "deluxe" part (probably easy on consoles - just insert the disk and wait. Steam... I fear the installer will download the updates and the dlc with no way to prevent that)